# Data wrangling in Python, calculate value from some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe in Python below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_3_MNTH_AGO': [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'F', 'F', 0, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_4_MNTH_AGO' : [0, 2, 'F', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_5_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_6_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_7_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_8_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_9_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_10_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2, 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_11_MNTH_AGO' : [4, 3, 2, 'F', 2, 0, 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO' : ['F', 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2]
})

df.head()
```

I want to convert those values (string value: C, F, and Z) into some categories with this condition: if values in column CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO, CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO, ......., CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO consist:

```
C = 0
F = 0
Z = 0
else value  = value 

#Convert value
df = df.replace({'C': 0, 'F': 0, 'Z': 0,' ':0}).astype(int)
```

Then, I want to create a new column with the name of MSD. MSD stands for Month Since Delinquent. MSD is calculated by identifying each of 12 columns CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO, CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO, .......up until CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO with this kind of condition:

```
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 1, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 2, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_3_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 3, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_4_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 4, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_5_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 5, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_6_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 6, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_7_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 7, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_8_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 8, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_9_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 9, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_10_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 10, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_11_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 11, otherwise MSD=0 or
If value in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO > 1 then MSD = 12, otherwise MSD=0
Note: otherwise if value 1 and 0, then MSD = 0.
```

For example:
[image]

- index 0, MSD =1,because value 3 > 1 is in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO
  (we no need to check CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO > 1 because we have
  found month since delinquent in CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO) , hence
  MSD is in 1 MNTH AGO
- index 1, **MSD=1**,
- index 2, **MSD=2**,
- index 3, **MSD=2**, because value 3 > 1 is in
  CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO, hence MSD is in 2 MNTH AGO
- index 4, **MSD=2**

*Note:* by checking each 12 columns with those conditions, If all values = 0 in each column CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO, .....and CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO, then MSD should be = 0.

Generally it is to check value > 1 in each 12 columns then determine the MSD value based on column name ***CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_x_MNTH_AGO***, *x will be the value of MSD if > 1.*

Comment: what's not working about the code you proposed? we're not here to write your whole program for you - if you're stuck somewhere you can ask a specific question or post an error you're trying to debug. otherwise, this question is likely to be closed for lack of focus. see [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ain't pretty but this one-liner should do the trick ;)

```
df['MSD'] = (df > 1).astype(int).apply(lambda row: int(row.idxmax().split('_')[3]) if row.sum() >=1 else 0, axis=1)
```

basically - check which values are over 1, get the first column for each row which is above one (the MSD as you defined it), and don't forget to check the edge case when it is 0.

Comment: I've checked it, and the result was as same as what I expected. All is correct. Thank you I appreciate you doing this trick in order to create new column.